# Is it possible to have a walk between every two vertices of any arbitrary length in a graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have a very basic question. I was going through the topic ***Walks  in Graphs***. I was just wondering: Is it possible to have a walk between every two vertices $x$ and $y$ of any arbitrary length $l$ in $G$? Is it really possible for every connected graph? Here $G$ is connected graph. Thanks in advance. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the graph is connected and non-bipartite (i.e., contains an odd length cycle), then for all pairs of vertices $x$ and $y$, there exists some $L$ such that for all $\ell \geq L$ there is a walk from $x$ to $y$ of length $L$.

- We can achieve $\mathrm{dist}(x,y)+2k$ for all $k \geq 0$ by walking from $x$ to $y$, then walking back and forth along an edge $yz$ for some neighbour $z$ of $y$.
- We can achieve $L:=\mathrm{dist}(x,y)+2k+t$ for all $k \geq 0$ for some odd number $t$ by walking from $x$ to the odd cycle, around the odd cycle and back to $x$, then continuing as per the first bullet point.

By definition, it's not possible to walk from $x$ to $y$ in less than $\mathrm{dist}(x,y)$ steps.

If the graph is bipartite, then any walk on the graph alternates between colour classes; so either the number of odd-length walks or the number of even-length walks from $x$ to $y$ is $0$ (depending on whether or not $x$ and $y$ are in the same colour class).