# length of a walk in product graph

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, algebraic-graph-theory

[image]

[image]

I was doing tensor product of graphs. We know that to find a walk between every two vertices *x and y* of any arbitrary length *l* in ***G***, the graph must contain an odd cycle. I am stuck here. Is it possible to find *l* that is common for every pair of vertices. I mean to find an *l* such that every pair of vertices have a walk of length *l* between them. Or any particular type of graph where this is possible. Any kind of help or suggestion will be helpful, Thanks a lot.

**Can we find such n that satisfies the Prop 5.7 for every pair of vertices in G and H? Actually i want the max{d(a,b),(c,d)} where a and c are in G, b and d are in H**

Also Its related to my last post on thi page. I hope the following link will help

[Is it possible to have a walk between every two vertices of any arbitrary length in a graph?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391247/is-it-possible-to-have-a-walk-between-every-two-vertices-of-any-arbitrary-length)

Comment: What do you mean by:"We know that to find a walk between every two vertices x and y of any arbitrary length $l$ in $G$, the graph must contain an odd cycle". If $l=1$ it's not sufficient, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the previous question you link to in this question, the answer by Doug Stones shows, assuming the graph is not bipartite, why for each pair $(x,y)$ of vertices there is a positive integer $L$ such that, for each length $l\ge L$, there is a path from $x$ to $y$ of that length $l$.

Since a graph with $n$ vertices has less than $n^2$ pairs $(x,y)$ of vertices for which a path is sought, you can use the above result and define $L^*$ to be the maximum value of $L(x,y)$ for all the pairs $(x,y)$ of vertices, where by $L(x,y)$ is meant some choice of $L$ for vertices $x,y$ as in the result above. Then if you choose any particular $l \ge L^*$ there will be (uniformly in the choice of $x,y$) a path of that length $l$ from $x$ to $y$.

Comment: you mean to say that after taking maximum of all *L* we will get a particular *L'*. and for any two vertices x and y, we will get a walk of length L'. x and y arbitrary. Am I right ??

Comment: @monalisa  That is correct, if $L'$ is the max of all the $L$, one $L$ for each pair $(x,y)$ of vertices in the graph. I just called that max by the symbol $L^*$ instead of $L'$. Also the same thing holds if we look at any fixed length $L''\ge L'.$